# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, permissions, errno

I'm trying to write in a txt file the vertices of a spline mesh, but I get this error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C\:Windows\system32\vt_84.txt

The code is

Comment: `C\:Windows\system32\vt_84.txt` - something's definitively is wrong with this path, dont you think?

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32` is a protected system folder. Try putting your file somewhere else, like `C:\Users\your_user_name\Desktop`.

Answer (score 2):

Try at a different location. Since you are trying to edit a file kept at C:Windows\system32 location, you are getting this error.

also, check your path. It should be like C:\Windows\system32\vt_84.txt

Answer (score 2):

If it's an existing file, make sure that it isn't open anywhere