# Extracting image from Word document. Getting PermissionError

Tags: python

The task is kinda simple - extract an image from Word document. Since I got a lot of files like more than 10000. I decide to implement multiprocessing for this task.

```
 import docx2txt
 import os
 from multiprocessing import Pool


 ABS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


 def extract_image(docs):
   for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(docs):
      for f in filenames:
          directory = os.path.join(ABS_PATH, "images/")
          docx2txt.process("%s%s" % (docs, f), directory)


def get_docs():
   source = os.path.join(ABS_PATH, 'docs/')
   return source

if __name__ == "__main__":
    docs = get_docs()
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(extract_image, docs)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I expect that images will be extracted to docs folder, but I get:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\pagefile.sys'

Comment: Chk this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093874/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied & this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501476/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-c-pagefile-sys